# Spring boot ServletException after LDAP authentication on Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

My spring boot app works correctly when I access it locally on localhost:8080. It authenticated correctly with the LDAP server.

When I deploy it on Apache Tomcat/7.0.76 I get the following error after I authenticate with LDAP:

```
2021-09-13 11:07:19,814 ERROR org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter [http-bio-8080-exec-462] Forwarding to error page from request [/login] due to except
ion [Filter execution threw an exception]
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:267)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)

...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.changeSessionId()Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.applySessionFixation(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:40)
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>xxx.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx-linkingservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>xxx-linkingservice</name>
    <description>xxx</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tag::when deployed to an external tomcat server include scope=provided[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tag::security[] -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- tag::attributes is configured on the apache server[] -->
        <finalName>attributes</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried different spring boot parent releases but it did not help. I also cannot find a suitable answer on SO.

**Update:**

Following @M.Deinum comment I added the following dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but this did not help. It appears the method `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.changeSessionId()` requires servlet 3.1 as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#changeSessionId--) and I was hoping adding a servlet-api 3.1 dependency would help.

Comment: Your tomcat version is too old, you need at least 8.5 older versions don't support Servlet 3.1.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum Is there a way to load Servlet 3.1 on Tomcat 7.0.76 somehow?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, as that supports version 2.5 as a max. version and is build as such. The servlet API is part of the server not the application.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum I tried adding the servlet-api 3.1.0 dependency in pom as described in the question update but it did not help.

Comment: @Anuska: you misinterpreted Deinum's remark. Tomcat 7.0 is an implementation of Servlet 3.0, nothing less, nothing more (and a couple of other specification). If you add Servlet API 3.1 to your project Tomcat will not magically implement it!

Comment: as pointed out, when you add `javax-servlet-api` all you get is an api which basically means, that all you get are a bunch of empty interfaces. When your code calls one of those interface functions, you get a `NoSuchMethodError` because the interface tries to find the implementation of that interface, your version of tomcat does not have that code. If you want that code, you need to upgrade tomcat, you cant just magically pull in version 8.5 of tomcat into version 7.x. That is what is called to UPGRADE. So you need to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @Toerktumlare. I asked for a new version of Tomcat.